# Postbuild event exited with error code 1

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2013, post-build-event

I have a project in Visual studio 2013. I want to run unit tests after every build.
I have the following Post build event command line.

"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\MSTest.exe"  /testcontainer:"G:\VS PROG\CMP PORTAL\POCs\WebApiEx\Test\bin\Debug\Test.dll" which gives the following error,

Error 1 The command ""C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\MSTest.exe"  /testcontainer:"G:\VS PROG\CMP PORTAL\POCs\WebApiEx\Test\bin\Debug\Test.dll"" exited with code 1.  WebApiEx

Can any one help me?

Comment: Run this program in the Console window: what result do you have?

Comment: It works fine in console. Tests are running and trx file is generated.